# Bash redirection: append to a file descriptor (2>>&1)

Tags: bash, io-redirection, file-descriptors

I'm trying to append the output of a command (stdout and stderr) to an existing file.

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
command >>file 2>>&1
```

The problem is that `2>>&1` throws an error, but `>>file 2>>file` does not.

So, I think I'm misunderstanding how redirection works, or what is a file descriptor and what information is saved inside it.

Summarizing, what is the difference between the two following commands, and why the first one does not work, but the second one works?

```
command >>file 2>>&1      #not working
command >>file 2>>file    #working
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

What you want to do is set up file descriptor 1 (stdout) to append to a file, then redirect fd 2 (stderr) to simply do what fd 1 is doing.

```
command >>file 2>&1
```

You get an error with `2>>&1` simply because `>>&` is not a redirection operator.

Read [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) in the bash manual, particularly sections 3.6.5 and 3.6.8

Answer (score 12):

Since this is tagged with `bash`, you can use `&>>` to redirect (appending) both stdout and stderr.

`command &>>file`

Comment: This seems to be bash 4+ - version 3.2.x (on MacOS Catalina) doesn't support it but 4.x on most current Linux does.